# Socket.io async/await for .on()

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm building a socket.io Node JS application and my socket.io server will be listening for data from many socket.io clients, I need to save data to an API via my socket.io server as quickly as possible and figure that async/await is the best way forward.

Right now, I've got a function inside my `.on('connection')`, but is there a way I can make this an async function rather than have a nested function inside?

```js
io.use((socket, next)  => {

  if (!socket.handshake.query || !socket.handshake.query.token) {
    console.log('Authentication Error 1')
    return
  }

  jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, process.env.AGENT_SIGNING_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Authentication Error 2')
      return
    }
    socket.decoded = decoded
    next()
  })

}).on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('agent-performance', data => {
    async function savePerformance () {
      const saved = await db.saveToDb('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profiler/save', data)
      console.log(saved)
    }
    savePerformance()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but you'll probably want to keep your current code if there can be multiple `agent-performance` events. You can modify the following, but it'd be messy and less readable. Event emitters still exist for a reason, they're not made obsolete by the introduction of promises. If it's performance you're after, your current code is probably faster and more resistant to backpressure and easier to error-handle.

---

[`events.on`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/events.html#events_events_on_emitter_eventname_options) is a utility function that takes an event emitter (like `socket`) and returns an iterator that yields promises. You can await those with `for await of`.

[`events.once`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name_options) is a utility function that takes an event emitter (like `socket`) and returns a promise that resolves when the specified event is executed.

```
const { on, once } = require('events');

(async function() {
  // This is an iterator that can emit infinite number of times.
  const iterator = on(io, 'connection');
  // Yield a promise, await it, run what is between `{ }` and repeat.
  for await (const socket of iterator) {
    const data = await once(socket, 'agent-performance');
    const saved = await db.saveToDb(/* etc */);
  }

})();
```

As the names imply, `on` is similar to `socket.on` and `once` is similar to `socket.once`. In the above example:

- connected user 1, first agent-performance event: OK
- connected user 1, second agent-performance event: not handled, there's no more event handler, since `once` is "used up".
- connected user 2, first agent-performance event: OK

The documentation for `on` has a note about concurrency when using `for await (x of on(...))`, but I don't know if that would be a problem in your usecase.

> ```
>     // The execution of this inner block is synchronous and it
>    // processes one event at a time (even with await). Do not use
>    // if concurrent execution is required.
> ```